# iPhone - quick Navigation bar question

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigation bar in a few of my views without using a UINavigationController. So i dont use the navigation controller to push new views, I load new views again which have a "static" UINavigationBar at the top.

So currently the navigation bars just show the title of which ever view the user is looking at, they have no other function.

In some of my views I have a requirement to have a back button, about 3 views out of 10.

So I was wondering if it is possible for me to insert a back button that states back and goes back to the previous screen for just these 3 views, so I would have to be able to insert the back button and also detect when it was pressed.

Can I do this with my current set up or do I need to go back and create a view with a UINavigationController and use that to push and pop my views and somehow suppress the back button on the 7 screens that I dont want it to display on?

**EDIT:**

I've tried the following way:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBackButtonItemStyleBorder target:nil action:selector(myaction)];
[navItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButton]; //Doesn't work
[navItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backButton]; //Works but lacks the back arrow style of the back button
[backButton release];
```

So I can add a button but it doesn't look like the back button, is there a way to make it look like the back button or should I scratch and just use a UINavigationController? And if I do how can I suppress the back button when I dont want one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if i get you correctly. Just add a custom button to the navigation as `leftBarButtonItem` or `backBarButtonItem` and give it a custom button press action. in the button method you can remove this view and show your previous view. But that said the better way is to use normal `UINavigationController` if your app has Navigation bar in all screens.

Comment: Yeh I dont mind doing it the UINavigationController way it just means a bit more work having to redo my screens slightly and then suppress the back button on 7/10 of the screens.